# Prove that $(A,N;P,B)=(A,M;Q,C)=-1$ .

Tags: geometry

Given $\Delta ABC$ and incircle $\omega$ tangent to $BC,AC,AB$ at $Y,M,N$ respectively . Let $AY \cap \omega=X$ . Let the tangent through $X$ wrt $\omega$ intersect $AB$ and $AC$ at $P$ and $Q$ respectively .
Prove that $(A,N;P,B)=(A,M;Q,C)=-1$ .

[image]

I am completely stuck in this problem. I tried considering the intersection of $FE$ and $BC$, but no movement .

Comment: I didn't understand the meaning of the notations you used in "To prove...". Can you please explain?

Comment: @Shubhangi Are you sure that they are equal to $-1$?

Comment: @SarGe that is the cross ration notation

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg yes ..

Comment: @Shubhangi I think, they are equal to something positive.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg yes, the directed angles are coming out as positive .. I edited the question , it's actually a lemma which I need to prove ..

Comment: @Shubhangi, ok, got it. I think that proving your statement is equivalent to proving that "$B$ is harmonic conjugate of $P$ w.r.t. $A$ and $N$.

Comment: Cross ratio = $-1$ is a definition of harmonic conjugate of a triple of points. So, you just have to show that $P$ divides $AN$ in the same ratio internally, as $B$ does externally.

Comment: By Brianchon, $BQ, CP, XY, MN$ are concurrent. Can you finish it now?

Comment: Just to add timon's point more, notice if you let $MN \cap AY=J$ then $(AJ,XY)=-1$

Comment: @timon92 I am very new to Projective Geo, Can you if possible state the statement of Brianchon ?

Comment: @Shubhangi You can see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brianchon%27s_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z$ be a point on $AY$, different from $X$, such that $PX=PZ$. Then $\angle XZP = \angle PXZ = \angle XYB$, hence $PZ \parallel BY$. Hence $\dfrac{AP}{PZ} = \dfrac{AB}{BY}$. Since $PZ=PX=PN$ and $BY=BN$, we obtain $\dfrac{AP}{PN} = \dfrac{AB}{BN}$ which is equivalent to $(A,N;P,B)=-1$.

Answer (score 3):

If you familiar with harmonic quadrilaterals, then this can be proved in the following way.

Let $T$ be the intersection of the incircle and line $YP$ (and $Y\neq T$). Then, the quadrilateral $YNTX$ is harmonic. Indeed, it's cyclic and tangents at points $X$ and $Y$ intersect at point $P$ on line $YT$. Thus,
$$
(Y,T;N,X)=-1.
$$
Now, note that
$$
(Y,T;N,X)=(B,P;N,A),
$$
because we can project the incircle onto line $AB$ from point $Y$ (lines $YY$, $YT$, $YN$ and $YX$ intersect line $AB$ at points $B$, $P$, $N$ and $A$, respectively). Therefore,
$$
(B,P;N,A)=-1,~\text{so}~(A,N;B,P)=-1,
$$
as desired. Similarly, we can show that $(A,M;Q,C)=-1$.

Comment: Here, line $YY$ is the tangent to the incircle at point $Y$.

Comment: Really great solution !!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

It's well known that $BQ, CP, XY, NM$ concur say at $O$. Taking perspectivity at $O$, we get
$$(AM;QC)\overset{O}{=}(AN;PB)$$
To show that this is a harmonic bundle note that $$(AN;PB)=-1\implies \frac{AP}{NP}=\frac{AB}{NB}\iff \frac{AP}{PX}=\frac{AB}{BY}$$
Now as $\angle PXY =\angle BYX$, we get $\frac{AP}{PX}=\frac{AB}{BY}$ by ratio lemma. Completeing the proof.

Comment: well, how do you get the last part ?

Comment: @Shubhangi That's just converse of Thales Theorem

Comment: i see.. .. I must have understood the question wrongly..Thanks!

Comment: The last equivalence is incorrect. The problem statement is true by the way, I'll post an elementary solution in a sec.

Comment: @timon92 Yeah, I fixed it

Comment: @Anand how did you get ", we get /=/" ?

Comment: @Shubhangi Just use ratio lemma (basically sine rule) in triangle $APX$ and $ABY$ by noting that $\sin \angle AXP = \sin \angle AYB$.

Comment: @Anand Thanks , I got it ... BTW congrats for SOR !!

Comment: @Shubhangi Thank you :)...How do you know bout SOR?